# Why does 1 == int evaluates to False?

Tags: python

Why does this print False in Python 3?

```
>>> 1 == int
False
```

Comment: Because you're comparing two objects that one of that has the value of 1 and other one doesn't have a value at all. `int` is actually a type object. It denotes a type in python and  `1` is an `int` type object.

Comment: Of course `int` has a value; it's just not an *integer* value, but a type value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that isn't at all doing what you think it is. You are comparing the integer value `1` with the *type* `int`; naturally they are not equal.

If you want to check whether an object is of a certain type, use `isinstance`:

```
isinstance(1, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you want to use is this:

```
>>> type(1) is int
True
```

or

```
>>> type(1) == int
True
```